# How to understand “We would like you…

Tags: grammar

1. We would like you to buy the tickets for us.
2. We would rather you bought the tickets for us.
3. We would rather you buy the tickets for us.

1=2 or 1=3, and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They aren't equal.

#2 ("we would rather you bought...") is wrong, as the simple past doesn't work here.

#1 uses "would like" which expresses that the speakers want you to do something. It is a polite request (but also suggests an air of authority over the listener - such as a parent speaking to a child or a manager to an employee).

#3 uses "would rather" which expresses a preference for one thing over another. The other thing here is an implicit alternative, such as the speakers buying the tickets themselves. It is more of a statement than a request, although it can be taken as an indirect request.